# Excel Form Controls Don’t Have Properties

Tags: excel, properties, form-control, vba

Why is there no way to access Excel’s **Form Controls** *properties*? In *Design Mode* when, for e.g. button is right-clicked, the only options that pop-up are:

- Cut
- Copy
- Paste
- Edit Text
- Grouping
- Order
- Assign Macro
- Format Control

When clicking on *Properties* under *Controls* on the *Developer* tab, the only control that appears in the drop down is **Sheet1 Worksheet**.

Is there a setting that needs enabling or am I forced to use an **ActiveX Control?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want those properties, you have to use ActiveX. Form controls are designed to be simpler, but with fewer options, like properties and events. Form controls still have properties, just not as many and you can't access them from a property sheet like first class Excel objects. You can still manipulate them through the UI and through VBA.

Comment: Thanks Dick. I figured as much. Had trouble deleting the button through VBA because I didn’t know its name, but just a while ago after playing around discovered where its name can be changed.

Comment: Where can it's name be changed?

Comment: Form Control properties can be accessed: `Dim x As Object:  Set x = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Check Box 1")`